# Google sheets API append method

Tags: google-sheets-api

It seems to me that the google sheets API's append method, the method which is used to add data to google sheet from your program, expects a 2d array. Sam Berlin here seems to say as much [Google Sheet API batch update issue iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901386/google-sheet-api-batch-update-issue-ios). I was wondering if anyone knows why this is?

Answer (score 0):

If you go the reference page for the method [`sheets.value.append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) you will see that the values that you need to introduce is an object of the type [`ValueRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) and from the documentation you can actually see:

> **`values[]`** The data that was read or to be written. This is an array of arrays, the outer array representing all the data and each inner array representing a major dimension. Each item in the inner array corresponds with one cell.

And why is done that way... well your guess is as good as mine.

Having a standardized object to represent values of a given range (input or output) is a plus when working with any API. Also in cases you want to add more than one row/column at a time you can do it easily by providing a 2-D array, when there would be as arrays as rows/columns you want to insert (as stated by the documentation).

**TL;DR**: 2-D array are very good analogue of the values inside a range inside a spreadsheet.